# How to display an Angular Material mat-form-field as disabled with label and value

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to display a `mat-form-field` as disabled with label at the top and the value at the bottom in the `input` field. I tried `<mat-hint>` but it displays at the bottom.

What should I do to have the label at the top and `input` control at the bottom.

[image]

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput disabled placeholder="FirstName">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `component.ts` import and add this providers

```
import { MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

in your `@Component({})` of your `component.ts`

```
providers: [{provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {floatLabel: 'always'}}]
```

Your `@Component({})` should look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-group-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'mat-group-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['mat-group-overview-example.css'],
  providers: [{provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {floatLabel: 'always'}}]
})
```

you will achieve this `<mat-form-field>`

[image]